# Why doesnt the password work when I enter it?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys
import string
import time

password  = "1234"
guess = " "
count = 0
def bank():
     print("TKS Bank")
     print("Enter your pin below to access your TKS Bank account")
     print()
def password():
     global password
     global guess
     global count
     while count != 3 and guess != password:
          guess = input("Please enter your 4 digit pin: ")
          count += 1
          if guess == password:
               menu()
          elif count == 3:
               print("Number of tries maxed.")
               countdown()
               count = 0
          else:
               print("Your pin is denied, Try again")

def menu():
     print("Your pin has been approved")
     print("_" * 80)
     print("Welcome to the TKS Bank")
     print("_" * 80)
     print("1. Type 1 to check your account balance")
     print("2. Type 2 to to deposit a chosen amount")
     print("3. Type 3 to withdraw a chosen amount")
     print("4. Type 4 to check your simple interest")
     print("5. Type 5 to exit the menu")
     print("_" * 80)

def balance():
     balance = (random.randint(1,1000))

     print("$", balance)
#'sys' imports the system library from the python library
def quit():
     os.exit(0)

def countdown():
     print("You have been locked out for 3 minutes. Please come back later 
and try again")
     time.sleep(3)
bank()
password()
```

When I have the countdown function the password does not work and just continually loops. Does anyone have a fix?

To expand with the countdown function when I input the correct password it says that it is incorrect and goes to the countdown after three tries. I really don't know what the solution is so anyone help would be appreciated.

Comment: By the time you reach your `password` function, `password` is a function, not a string.  Give one of them a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `def password():` function, there's an ambiguous name usage between `password` the variable and `password` the function.